# Timepiker value is not going to php database (Datatype : datetime) variable?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, laravel-5

I take time piker to take time from my web page.
This is my front end code.

```
   <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" id="event_start_timepicker" placeholder="select time" name="startAt">
```

I use Laravel 5 frame work . so I access this data in my controller class. I want to sent this value in my phpMyAdmin database **datetime** varable.

This is my controller class code.

```
 public function store(Request $request) {
    //
    $event = Request::all();

    //dd($event['startAt']);  out put : "02:45 PM" //data is comming correctly

    //try to format data
    $s_time = date_create($event['startAt'])->format('Y-m-d h:i:s A');
    $e_time = date_create($event['endAt'])->format('Y-m-d h:i:s A');

    //reassigning format data
    $event['startAt']=$s_time;
    $event['endAt'] =$e_time;

    Event::create($event);
    return redirect('event');
}
```

first time I run without formate  , I check database and I see  datetime variable value is 0000-00-00 00:00:00 . so , I formate but still same result other  all details passed correctly. expect some answer. please help me.

this is script.

```
                //Timepicker
                $("#event_start_timepicker").timepicker({
                    showInputs: false,
                    format:"yyyy-mm-dd h:i:s A"
                });

                $("#event_end_timepicker").timepicker({
                    showInputs: false,
                    format:"yyyy-mm-dd h:i:s A"
                });
```

Comment: We would need the jQuery `timepicker` declaration as well.

Comment: @D4V1D I added script code too.

Comment: Why would you `format('Y-m-d h:i:s A')` when data is outputted as such: `02:45 PM`? Just do `format('h:i:s A');`.

Comment: @D4V1D , my database variable data type is "datetime" . so , i think without date , it not go to database. so , i did it, I will try without it.but result is same. :-(

Comment: Your database field type is datetime so you need to convert date in (Y-m-d H:i:s) not (Y-m-d H:i:s A). just try it out.

Comment: @kevin now it is ok..............!